# Error: Could not download sdklib.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:25.1.2): No cached version available for offline mode

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android Studio and I am getting these kind of errors. 
I don't understand what is this.
Can anyone please tell me on how to solve this ?

Here is my Event Log:

```
16:03:53 Gradle sync started
16:03:55 Gradle sync failed: Could not download
 sdklib.jar(com.android.tools:sdklib:25.1.2): No cached version available
 for offline mode
 Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```